# addEventHandler to every element in a class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an event listener to all elements with a class of section, however it only applies it to the last object in the node list.

```
var section = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
for(var i=0;i<section.length;i++){
var elem = section[i];
elem.addEventListener('click', function () {move (elem)}, false); 
}
```

Is there a way I can add the event listener for each one?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example for the generic answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that there's no block scope in JavaScript. So `elem` is overwritten each iteration, instead of being declared as a new variable each time. The only way to declare new variables in each iteration is through a function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < section.length; i++){
  (function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() { move(elem); }, false);
  })(elem);
}
```

But `addEventListener` sets `this` to the element, so in your case you can neatly do:

```
for(var i = 0; i < section.length; i++){
  elem.addEventListener('click', function () { move(this); }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that's because you are referencing `elem` and `i` inside function. I can suggest trying

```
var section = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
for(var i=0;i<section.length;i++){
    var handler = (function(ind){ 
        return function () {
             move (section[ind]);
        }
    })(i) 

    elem.addEventListener('click', handler, false); 
}
```

Comment: This will fail as well because `i` is declared in the same scope.

Comment: In this case you can just do `move(this)`.

Comment: @pimvdb,yes! that's true, why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: Because this question is asked so often... But I've posted :)

Comment: I'd updated my question as well and suggested generating handler on fly as well